# How to get a date out of Gregorian String?

Tags: java, date, calendar, gregorian-calendar

```
public Calendar getDateAfterXYearYMonthZDays(Calendar calendar) {

        Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);
        c.add(Calendar.YEAR, 2);
        c.add(Calendar.MONTH,1);

        return c; 
    }
```

I am getting a Gregorian String but I want "Sat Aug 22 22:07:27 IST 2015" and that too should be returned in the above method.

Comment: If you want to return a string, you need to change the method signature.

Comment: "I am getting a Gregorian String" - what do you mean by that? (Your method isn't returning a string at all...)

Comment: your method argument should be `String` and return type should be `Date`

Comment: see my problem statement was that I have to add X months,Y days,Z years and in the class diagram I was having this method  

public Calendar getDateAfterXYearYMonthZDays(Calendar calendar)

and I have called this method in the main class where I am using sysout to print it and through their I am getting Gregorian Calendar.

Comment: @SidharthKhera Thanks for participating in StackOverflow. Usually this site works better if you edit your Question to provide clarification rather than posting as comments. Look for the "edit" link below your question's text and tags (if using a web browser). Your original question is *not* clear about adding months/days. Also, please search StackOverflow before posting. Your issues have already been asked and answered many times before.

Answer (score 1):

Question is not clear but as far I as understood you have a `Calendar` and you want `String` out of it. First change your method signature to return `String` then get `Date` instance from `Calendar` and use `SimpleDateFormatter` to format the `Date`.

Also you're never using method parameter `calendar`. Initialize before passing it as an argument.

```
public String getDateAfterXYearYMonthZDays(Calendar calendar) {

    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);
    calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 2);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH,1);

    SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("E M d HH:mm:ss z d");
    return formatter.format(c.getTime() );        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use JodaTime instead as it will save you a lot of headaches.

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

In JodaTime you can do the following,

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
String myDateTimeString = dateTime.toString("E M d HH:mm:ss z y");
// myDateTimeString's value - Weekday Month Day Time TimeZone Year
```

Here is the doc page showing other formatting types.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

JodaTime also supports Gregorian calendar systems and provides some helper methods to convert from Calendar to a JodaTime.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the date using below code :

```
public Date getDateAfterXYearYMonthZDays(String gregorianString) {

        SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");

        Date formattedDate = null;

        try {
            formattedDate = formatter.parse(gregorianString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return formattedDate;
    }
```